# How to use an M.domain.com address for mobiles with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

Say I have an ASP.Net MVC webiste hosted at www.somedomain.com. Now I am interested in providing a mobile version at m.somedomain.com. Do I need to completely rewrite the site or can MVC detect the browser type and route through to mobile optimised pages automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the browser type and do routing, but you have to do some work yourself - it's not really built in. Scott Hanselman has some great example code here:

[Mix: Mobile Web Sites with ASP.NET MVC and the Mobile Browser Definition File](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx)